# Changing number precision

Tags: c++

How would you change the precision of a number for example: `float n = 1.2345` and store it back to the variable 'n' with changing it to `1.23` ?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're asking how to round a number? You'll find a lot of previous questions if you search for that.

Comment: Do you want to round numbers or truncate them? what should happen when n = 1.246?

Comment: Yes, truncate the number and put it back to the variable 'n'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
float n = 1.2345;
int scaled = n * 100
n = static_cast<float>(scaled)/100.0;
```

or in one line:

```
n = static_cast<float>( static_cast<int>(n*100) ) / 100;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <cmath>

n = roundf(n * 100.0f) / 100.0f;
```

or if you need to truncate rather than round:

```
n = truncf(n * 100.0f) / 100.0f;
```

Comment: Just a note: this rounds the floating point number instead of truncating it, which may or may not be what Dave18 is looking for.

Comment: @Bill: indeed - I was updating it to include the possibility of truncation at the exactly the same time that you were adding your comment. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this question :

[Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

However, in C++, if you need to round a number for display purpose, I wouldn't use `printf`, but use the stream operators :

```
using namespace std;
cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2);
cout << n;
```

Comment: Odd that this got downvoted, when it's the only answer mentioning display purposes, which could well be the OP's use case! +1.

Comment: @Jefromi : yep, don't know why it was downvoted. I wish the downvoter would put an explaination.

Thx for upvoting !

Answer (score 2):

`float truncated = static_cast<int>(n * 100) / 100.0f` ought to work.