# Updating variable values with setprecision

Tags: c++, precision

I'm building a calculator application that will calculate the exact net pay after taxes. The problem I am having is that the program automatically rounds the values up.

I tried using setprecision, but it seems to only work when used in a cout or cin line. That would require user input, the values I need to apply setprecision on are determined by the program itself. For instance, if I place setprecision on line 42, which updates the variable 'federal', the compiler returns an error expecting a ';' prior to it. How can I set the precision of a variable without requiring user input.

To clarify, the only variables which the user enters are 'hours' and 'payrate'. The other variables are interacted with like the example below.

```
40 if ((gross >= 0) && (gross < 260))
41     {
42         federal = ((gross - 73) * .1);
43     }
```

Comment: More code context please.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing number precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069950/changing-number-precision)

Comment: What is the type of `gross`? If it's a floating point type, you may consider functions like [`std::round`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) or [`std::ceil`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil). [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) is an input/output manipulator which doesn't affect the value of your variable, but only how it is outputted, e.g. in `std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << gross << '\n';`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out my mistake here. I was declaring the variables at integers, forgetting integers are whole numbers, so I changed it to floats, and that fixed it.