# Conversion problem in ansi c

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy, atof

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

I need to convert some data from txt file into double value and I'm using this function for this : atof .
The problem is that the value which must be convert is 5.550000 and the atof function return 
5.5499999999999998 and this is a problem because I must calculate the GPA with this number and the reault is not precise.
This is the function which read the data from the txt file:

```
void readNext(FILE* file,Lab* lab)
{
    char line[100];
getline(file,line,100);
if (strcmp(line,"") == 0)
{
    lab->is_null = 1;
    return;
}
strcpy(lab->date,line);
getline(file,line,100);
lab->presence = atoi(line);
getline(file,line,100);
strcpy(lab->num_work,line);
getline(file,line,100);
lab->mark_work = atof(line);
getline(file,line,100);
lab->test_work = atof(line);
getline(file,line,100);
lab->current = atof(line);
getline(file,line,100);
lab->status_work = atoi(line);
getline(file,line,100);
}
```

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[drhirsch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193439/conversion-problem-in-ansi-c/6193833#6193833) is correct - 5.55 cannot be exactly represented in binary floating point (in the same way that 1 ÷ 7 cannot be exactly represented in decimal).

However, for your purposes, this shouldn't be a problem, because a float definitely *can* store 5.55 *accurate to three places*, which is the number you have.  This just means that you need to use the correct format when printing - in this case, `%.3g`.  When you calculate the GPA, your calculations will still be accurate to three places, because the calculation of an average doesn't cause catastrophic cancellation.

Answer (score 3):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c) StackOverflow article.

Floats will have issues representing exact values as you want without some additional work.  You'll face two issues (described in the linked post) - actual rounding and formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: `atof("5.55")` will never return an precise (meaning exact) representation of this decimal fraction, because there *exists* no exact binary floating point representation of this number, it's an infinite binary fraction.

For a long answer see http://www.math.umd.edu/~jkolesar/mait613/floating_point_math.pdf .