# How to round off decimal number to 2 digits in iphone?

Tags: iphone, rounding, nsformatter

How can we round off decimal numbers to 2 digits in iphone ?

For example ,

1. 5345 --> 53
2. 570 -- > 57
3. 89523  -- > 90

I tried to use nsformatter for this and here is the code i used ,

```
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumIntegerDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:570]];

    [formatter release];
    NSLog(@"%@",numberstring);
```

I keep on getting the value as 70 even after changing the rounding mode to different options. Please help me with this

Thanks,
Vinod.

Answer (score 11):

Use this simple code instead of formatter;

```
myFloat = roundf(100 * myFloat) / 100.0;
```

i hope it helps.

Or you can use this

```
float roundedValue = round(2.0f * number) / 2.0f;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2]; 
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];  
NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:roundedValue]]; 
[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're looking to round up the decimal digits, you should actually provide a float for this and set the maximum fractional digits to 2. You're probably looking for this,

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:570.57018]];

[formatter release];
NSLog(@"%@",numberString);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)   maybe this link helps.you can the convert the float result back to an nsnumber

Answer (score 0):

Deepak's answer is probably exactly what you need, but I'm just providing another option for the sake of options.  I'm assuming you're using `NSNumber` values, so `someNumber` will be of that type in the example:

```
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [someNumber floatValue]];
// this converts the NSNumber to a float, then formats the float in a string;
NSNumber *formattedNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[numberString floatValue]];
// this extracts the float from the string and puts it back as an NSNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems there is no direct way to round off a whole number

But you can still do it. You have to do some extra work to convert the whole number to a fractional number and some trick to remove the "0." from the float value.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

int n = 570;
float f = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.%d", n] floatValue];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:f];
NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
[formatter setPositivePrefix:@"0."];
number = [formatter numberFromString:str];
[formatter release];
```