# Round NSNumber to a specific number of significant digits

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

Let's say I have an `NSNumber` object that holds a value `0.12345`. All I want is an `NSNumber` object with a same value, but rounded to a specified number of significant digits, say 2, so value looks like this: `0.12`.

- I don't want to convert it to `NSString` and back, which is what some of [the answers suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305256/how-to-round-off-decimal-number-to-2-digits-in-iphone)
- I would prefer not to cast/convert and/or do multiplication/division manually [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

Is there an obvious way to do it that I am missing?

Comment: `NSNumber` doesn't have any built-in rounding functions.  You could use `NSDecimalNumber` which does.

Comment: Explain your goal a bit more. Why do you need to round the `NSNumber`?

Comment: "I would prefer not to ..." - explain why you don't want to solve a math problem with math. There are plenty of answers in your linked question, ranging from bad to good (the scores will help with that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty much impossible to do it and maintain all your constraints. `NSNumber` has no rounding methods, so you're going to have to convert to something else. The obvious route is to convert to a double and multiply, round and divide, but you say you would prefer not to do that. So that leaves this route:

```
NSNumber *round(NSNumber *number, NSInteger places, NSRoundingMode mode) {
    NSDecimal d = number.decimalValue;
    NSDecimal rd;
    NSDecimalRound(&rd, &d, places, mode);
    return [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:rd];
}
```

Comment: this is the closest to what I had it mind, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Another hacky way is:

1. Convert your number to round after multiplied it by 100.

int yourNum = 0.12345 * 100;
yourNum now is 12.

2. Then whenever you need the number just divide by 100.

float yourNumF = yourNum / 100.0;

Not a fan of this method myself but it fits your requirement. :D