# C++ how to set a fixed decimal precision for a float

Tags: c++, boost, rounding, numeric-conversion

I have an API call which returns a double. The double's decimal length can variate from many decimal places to a few (it all comes down to the state of an actuator). This double represents the current position on the range radius of an actuator.
I am not interested in such a detailed number, because it adds alot of noise to the system. 
I've been using floats to save space, but still I have floats which have 6-8 decimal length.
I am not interested in floor or ceil, simply because it doesn't do the job i want.
For example, I have the numbers:

```
-2.05176
-0.104545
 0.30643
 0.140237
 1.41205
-0.176715
 0.559462
 0.364928
```

I want the precision to be set to 2 decimal places no matter what.
I am NOT talking about the output precision on std::cout, I know how to set this. I am talking about the actual precision of the float. i.e: I am interested in floats who will have 0.XX format and 0.XX00000000000 actual precision.
Therefore transforming the above list to:

```
-2.05
-0.10
 0.30
 0.14
 1.41
-0.17
 0.55
 0.36
```

I know boost has a numerical conversion template, but I cannot figure out how to convert from float to float using a lower precision. Can somebody please help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you just round it.

```
float round(float num, int precision)
{
    return floorf(num * pow(10.0f,precision) + .5f)/pow(10.0f,precision);
}
```

Comment: This is so funny. Your floats are held with a precision fixed by the implementation. If you want exact values use integers. Otherwise you should just be rounding the values when printing and the output functions have this built in.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said Martin. Care to explain ? As I said i am not interested in printing values, but rounding them to a 2 point precision and comparing them.

Answer (score 2):

The precision of float and double is down to the hardware. Anything else needs to be coded in software.

You could try scaling instead, working in ints:

```
-205
 -10
  30
  14
 141
 -17
  55
  36
```

Comment: I have thought about scalling, but it isn't enough accurate either. If for example the range of an actuator is -1.50 up to 3.50, I only need the two decimal range, anything more is just adding noise, anything less is generalizing too much.