# How to keep c++ from adding extra decimals when casting from float to double (not for IO)?

Tags: c++, precision

The problem I'm facing is because I'm using a library that when fed a `float`, it does something inside that is converting the float to double and adding a lot of decimals to the number which is not right. I mean, is right according to how doubles and floats are represented and what naturally happens when you cast, but it is not right for my application. I have `16.3` as `float` and I need that to be `16.3` as `double`.

I'm trying to cast the float to double BEFORE passing the value to the library to have control over that conversion but so far I haven't found a straightforward way of doing so. I just want to know if it is possible to cast a 16.3 from `float` to `double` and have the same 16.3 as a result.

```
float f_var = 16.3;            // f_var is 16.3
double d_var = (double)f_var;  // d_var shall be also 16.3, not 16.299999237060547
```

Is there even a proper way of doing this in C++? Or I would have to do something like:

```
char float_buf[10];
float f_var = 16.3;
sprintf(float_buf, "%.2f", f_var);
double d_var = atof(float_buf);
```

Because that works, but I'd like to see if there is a "proper" way of doing this in c++.

There is [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657858/c-how-to-set-a-fixed-decimal-precision-for-a-float) in SO with another proposed solution but it involves multiplication and a division that I would like to avoid as well.

This is not for displaying or any input/output operation or converting to a string, I know how to do that and there is a lot of information about it. Additionally, I'm not trying to understand "why" this happens, there is a lot of information about that as well.

Also, most of the answers in SO that may cause this question to be marked as duplicate are not for C++, they are mostly for C#, Java JS, Objective C, etc. For the few I found for C/C++, most of them are dealing with this issue for IO with `printf` or `cout` and the others only explain why this happens which is also not useful. If you have indeed a duplicate for this exactly in C++ then please indicate. I'll be happy for this to be flagged as duplicate if it really is.

Thanks!

Comment: You basically can't.  What you need is a fixed point library or an arbitrary precision library.  Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: You wrote `float f_var = 16.3;` presumably expecting `f_var` to be exactly `16.3`. It isn't, because it cannot be. There is no floating point value in this here world that can exactly represent the number 16.3, regardless of whether you are using C, C++, PHP or a devil with horns and hooves.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the multiplication and division? That's the "right" way to do this. Your way is... explicit... but otherwise probably much, (maybe even *very* much?) slower. Also, duplicates are duplicates, and IEEE floating point is IEEE floating point. Java, C++, C#, C, *doesn't matter* (that much) when it comes to these questions. Notice that the two "right" solutions you've found translate directly to pretty much any language related to C, and more besides. I doubt you're going to get an answer that's specific to C++ that's better than anything you've found in any language.

Comment: I would advise you to find a different library that uses doubles instead of floats if this is that important to you.

Comment: `float f_var = 16.3;            // f_var is 16.3` - No, `f_var` is *not* `16.3` *exactly*, since that value cannot be exactly represented by a `float`. `f_var` holds the closest *aproximation* to `16.3` that a IEEE `float` can represent.

Comment: Using https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html shows that `16.3` as a float is actually `16.299999237060546875`

Answer (score 5):

This answer assumes IEEE floating point.

A machine data type such as `float` contains a finite number of bits and therefore can only represent a finite number of values. Alas, `16.3` doesn't happen to be one of those.

```
float f_var = 16.3;
```

The value of `f_var` is now the number that is (1) representable as a single precision floating point number and (2) as close to `16.3` as humanly possible. This number happens to be exactly `16.299999237060546875`. It is the closest one to `16.3`. The next larger representable number is `16.3000011444091796875`, which is quite a bit farther away. The binary representations of these two are `01000001100000100110011001100110` and `01000001100000100110011001100111` if you are curious. They are different only in the last bit.

```
double d_var = (double)f_var;
```

Lo and behold, the value of `d_var` is now the exact same number `16.299999237060546875`.

Is this the closest possible `double` number to `16.3`?  *Hell no!*

`double` can exactly represent `16.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125` which is quite a bit closer to `16.3` then `16.299999237060546875`.

But why should `d_var` take this more precise value? It has been shown `16.299999237060546875`, and now it is quite faithfully `16.299999237060546875`. If you want it to be more precise, assign it a more precise value. It is not a sentient being and doesn't know that you *meant* that `16.299999237060546875` to be `16.3`.

Where could one get such a more precise value from?

Well one could arbitrarily decide all the interesting numbers have no more than one digit after the decimal point, and an infinite number of zeroes after that. (Why would one ever assume that is beyond me, but I'm playing along). If this is the case, then

```
d_var = round(d_var * 10)/10
```

would *round* the number to be very close to the one that has one decimal digit after the decimal point, and an infinite number of zeroes after that. If we do this trick with `16.299999237060546875`, it will become `16.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125`.

If you are interested in numbers with two digits after the decimal point, replace 10 with 100, etc. However, at this point you should be asking ask yourself whether the floating point type is the right tool for the job. Maybe you need fixed-point decimal numbers?

On the other hand, if you are interested in numbers with *whatever number of digits there was initially*, then you have to supply that number of digits, and possibly remember it along with the number itself. At this point you should ask yourself the above question even harder.