# How to set precision of a float

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

Can someone explain me how to choose the precision of a float with a C function?

Examples:

`theFatFunction(0.666666666, 3)` returns 0.667

`theFatFunction(0.111111111, 3)` returns 0.111

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't do that, since precision is determined by the data type (i.e. `float` or `double` or `long double`). If you want to round it for printing purposes, you can use the proper format specifiers in `printf()`, i.e. `printf("%0.3f\n", 0.666666666)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Precision depends entirely on the data type. You've got `float` and `double` and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Floats have a static, fixed precision. You can't change it. What you can sometimes do, is round the number.

See [this page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/round/), and consider to scale yourself by powers of 10. Note that not all numbers are exactly representable as floats, either.

Comment: you can do floor(x*100)/100.0

Answer (score 2):

Most systems follow IEEE-754 floating point standard which defines several floating point types.

On these systems, usually `float` is the IEEE-754 `binary32` single precision type: it has 24-bit of precision. `double` is the `binary64` double precision type; it has 53-bit of precision.  The precision in bit numbers is defined by the IEEE-754 standard and cannot be changed.

When you print values of floating point types using functions of the `fprintf` family (e.g., `printf`), the precision is defined as the maximum number of significant digits and is by default set to 6 digits. You can change the default precision with a `.` followed by a decimal number in the conversion specification. For example:

```
printf("%.10f\n", 4.0 * atan(1.0));  // prints 3.1415926536
```

whereas

```
printf("%f\n", 4.0 * atan(1.0));     // prints 3.141593
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be roughly the following steps:

1. Add 0.666666666 with 0.0005 (we get 0.667166666)
2. Multiply by 1000 (we get 667.166666)
3. Shift the number to an int (we get 667)
4. Shift it back to float (we get 667.0)
5. Divide by 1000 (we get 0.667)

Thank you.