# Print a float in C with two decimals but no trailing zeroes

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, printf

Is there a simple, quick way in C to convert or print a float so that the output has a precision of two decimals (not more), but in case there are any trailing zeroes they get cut out?

Examples:

```
100.456 -> 100.46
100.32 -> 100.32
100.7046 -> 100.7
100.00 -> 100
```

Let's say we have `float x;` and we execute `printf(%.2f, x)`.
This would satisfy the first requirement, since any float would be printed with a maximum precision of 2 decimals. The problem though is that for `x=100.00` or `100.7046` we would get respectively `100.00` and `100.70`.

Using "g" as a format wouldn't fix the problem either. Any ideas?

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks, but the link that you suggest proposes using "g" as a format, which wouldn't actually solve my problem...

Comment: @Pensierinmusica: nevertheless, you have asked the same question as that other one. Since the first paragraph of the first answer isn't suitable, keep reading.

Comment: @SteveJessop reading carefully it's actually not the same question. The link that you're referring to accepts any number of relevant decimals, whereas in my example we're limiting it to 2.

Comment: @Pensierinmusica: The answer is the same: Print to a buffer, then edit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil isn't there really any easier way? Anything more practical or that could be achieved with just a few characters of code? Seems a bit crazy for such a simple task.

Comment: Sometimes, when doing computer programming, you have to program the computer.

Comment: 100.7056 is not rounded to 100.71; is this the intent?

Comment: Hi @EricBainville, thanks for pointing that out! I just corrected the example  :)

Answer (score -2):

`printf ("%.2f", 100.456);` should give you 100.46

Comment: What about `100.7056 -> 100.7` and `100.00 -> 100`.

Comment: I thought you were looking to preserve trailing zeroes, not remove them... [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c) is almost the exact same question and has several answers that might help you...

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer the question.