# Rounding 23.428 into 23.4

Tags: c++, rounding

**I need to round the answer 23.428 and get 23.4.**

I did a little search about it and I may need to include a line *float round (s)* but I did it and CODEBLOCKS gives me an error.

Note: the file Information.txt contains numbers 7.5 305.5 4.09 4

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   float m, k, kk;
   int n;
   float s;

   ifstream fd("Information.txt");
   fd >> k >> m >> kk >> n;



   k = k / 100;
   m = m * k;
   kk = kk * m;
   s = kk / n;

   /*s=((((k/100)*m)*kk)/n);*/



   fd.close();

   ofstream fr ("Rezults.txt");
   fr << s;
   fr.close();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating-point values (i.e. `float`s) usually aren't stored in base 10, but when you display their values they get converted to base 10 because that's what most of us are used to. Output streams (`std::cout` and the `fr` in the example) do this conversion, with a default precision of 6 digits. To display 3 digits, just change the precision:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    float num = 23.428;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << num << '\n';

    std::ofstream fr("Rezults.txt");
    fr << std::setprecision(3) << num << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for paying attention to my question and the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can just multiply the number by 10, round it and then divide by 10 again:

```
float x = 23.428;
x = std::round(10.0*x);
x /= 10.0;
```

Comment: Which in general won't work. The problem is that the question is about displaying base 10 values, while floating-point numbers are typically represented internally as base 2 values. There is no guarantee that you can convert a finite-length base 10 representation into a finite-length base 2 value. For example, `0.1` cannot be represented exactly as a binary value, and any display system that says the binary value is `0.1` is tinkering with the truth.