# What is wrong with C conversion character %.8f ?

Tags: c

when I try this code

```
printf("something %.8f",1.123456789);
```

It Gives This Result

```
1.12345679
```

There Is No 8 Why Is This

Comment: Do you know what [rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you expect the specifier `"%.8f"` to truncate the number at the 8th digit after decimal point. The precision specifier does, however, not truncate digits but rounds the number as stated in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24120950/2630032) (please upvote this reference if applicable):

> **C99 §7.19.6.1 The fprintf function; f,F**
>
> A double argument representing a floating-point number is converted to
>   decimal notation in the style [−]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits
>   after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision
>   specification. If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the
>   precision is zero and the # flag is not specified, no decimal-point
>   character appears. If a decimal-point character appears, at least one
>   digit appears before it. **The value is rounded to the appropriate
>   number of digits.**