# Why does printf output float 1.45 with one decimal place, and 1.445 with two decimal places in different behaviors?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, specifications

```
printf("%.1f, %.2f", 1.45, 1.445);
```

output

> 1.4, 1.45

1.45 is sliced but 1.445 is rounded.

I found this,
[Why printf round floating point numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120888/why-printf-round-floating-point-numbers#)
Which explained the specification recommands to round the float.

Edit:
I tested it with VS2017 (in a C++ project) and Dev-C.

Comment: Assuming your implementation uses IEEE-754 floats like many do, neither value has an exact representation. So the constant you write as `1.4` in the source code gets compiled to a double value which is close to, but not equal to, `1.4`. Which way it rounds afterwards is happenstance.

Comment: Try `printf("%.55f\n%.55f\n", 1.45, 1.445);` to see what the actual numbers are.

Comment: The question is in the topic name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Edited: I didn't originally print them to quite ridiculous enough levels of precision, so the answer gave incorrect reasoning behind the result.]

If you print them out to ridiculous levels of precision, the truth comes out:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
printf("%20.20f, %20.20f", 1.45, 1.445);
```

Result:

```
1.44999999999999995559, 1.44500000000000006217
```

So, as converted, 1.45 ends up ever so minutely *smaller* than 1.45, and 1.445 ends up every so slightly *greater* than 1.445.

So, of course, when we round 1.45, it rounds down, but when we round 1.445, it rounds upward.

Comment: Minor: width not needed. `"%.20f"` is enough to demo your good point.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same assumption. But I debugged the double value only with 7 or 8 decimal places and didn't see the "truth", haha.

Comment: @Zhang: 7 or 8 would be about enough to see the problem for a `float`, but the decimal precision of a `double` is normally around 16 places, so we'd expect everything to look "perfect" out to 8 places (and well beyond). On the other hand, there's no way to directly print out a `float` with `printf`--if you try to pass a `float`, it'll be promoted to `double` before it gets to `printf` (and this extra level of conversion can lead to even more confusion in a few rare cases).

Answer (score 2):

`double` encodes about 2<sup>64</sup> different values *exactly*.

Neither 1.45 nor 1.445 are in that large set of 2<sup>64</sup> values as those decimal values cannot be represented as a [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) values: some integer times a power of 2.

Instead of 1.45, 1.445, nearby values are used:

```
 1.45  --> 6530219459687219 * 2^-52 or about 1.449999999999999955591079... 
 1.445 --> 6507701461550367 * 2^-52 or about 1.445000000000000062172489...  or
```

OP's `printf()` performed a good job and rounded those values correctly.

```
printf("%.1f\n%.2f", 1.45, 1.445);
1.4     
1.45
```

Comment: Round off of `1.445000000000000062172489` is `1.44` (upto 2 decimal numbers). Am I wrong?

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula yes you are wrong for the default rounding modes, `1.445000000000000062172489` is more than `1.445` so will be rounded up to `1.45`

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula Depends on rounding mode.  The usual is round to nearest (ties to even).  1.445000000000000062172489... is closer to 1.45 than 1.44.