# Reading string in to float produces incorrect accuracy

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

Now I understand `float`s are less accurate than `double`, but does this explain when I have the `std::string`:

```
"7.6317"
```

and I do:

```
float x = atof(myString.c_str());
```

getting 7.63170004 is expected? Is there any way I can tell the assignment of x to only read the first 4 decimal places? Or is this because of the way the float representation stores the number 7.6317?

Comment: No, a `float` cannot store X decimal places. You can tell it to print with a specific precision. And `double` has the same behaviour. And use `std::stof`.

Comment: The closest float to 7.6317 is 7.631700038909912109375

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is expected. It is so-called floating point error.

Comment: This does answer the question "Is it expected".

Comment: 1. He asked if it is to be expected - I answered that, giving out tips where to look at.

2. I cannot comment any post other than mine ATM.

3. I would probably flag this post if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Some floating point literals do not have an accurate representation in the computer, even if -- in decimal notation -- the number seems harmless. This is because the computer uses 2 as a base. So even if a number might have a finite representation in base 10, it might not have on in base 2.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it like:

```
float x = floorf(val * 10000) / 10000;
```

i think it should work! see [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

Comment: What does this accomplish? The number is already rounded to four decimal places.

Comment: Yeah thats right, i forgot the float error with matisse and the exponent. sry