# Rounding a float to two decimal places

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

I wish to round a float value, say `val` to its nearest multiple of **0.05**. An explanation of my intent is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/457892/104443). I already have upper and lower bounds of `val`, say `valU` and `valL` respectively. I can do this in the following ways:

1. Search for the nearest multiple of **0.05** in the range `[valL, valU]` and assigning the value accordingly. Ties are settled by taking lower value. OR
2. Using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344261/842808) (off-course replacing 20 by 100 in the solution given in link).

I find that method-2 yields wrong results some times. Can someone please tell me why method-1 is right way?

Comment: Method 2 is best, show your code.

Comment: Be sure to post relevant material **here**.  Linked data is only reference data.

Answer (score 1):

> ... round a `float` value, say `val` to its nearest multiple of 0.05 ...

Given typical [binary floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), the best that can be had is

... round a `float` value to nearest to a multiple of 0.05 `R` and save as the nearest representable `float` `r`.

---

Method #1 is unclear in the corner cases.  What OP has is not code, but an outline of code from a math perspective and not an actual C code one.  I'd go with a variation on #2 that works *very* well. [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400691/rounding-a-float-to-two-decimal-places/39402171#comment66127717_39400691)

Almost method 2: Multiply, round, then divide.

```
#include <math.h>
double factor = 20.0;
float val = foo();
double_or_float rounded_val = round(val * factor)/factor;
```

This method has two subtle points that make it superior.

1. The multiplication is done with greater precision and range than the referenced answer - this allows for an *exact* product and a *very* precise quotient.   If the product/quotient were calculated with only `float` math, some edge cases would end up with the wrong answer and of course some large values would overflow to infinity.
2. "Ties are settled by taking lower value." is a tough and unusual goal.  Sounds like a goal geared to skew selection.  `round(double)` nicely rounds half way cases away from zero regardless of the current rounding direction.  To accomplish "lower", change the current rounding direction and use `rint()` or `nearbyint()`.

   ```
   #include <fenv.h>
   int current_rounding_direction = fegetround();
   fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
   double rounded_val = rint(val * factor)/factor;
   fesetround(current_rounding_direction);
   ```

---

> ... method-2 yields wrong results some times...

OP needs to post the code and the *exact* values used and calculated for a quality explanation of the strength/weakness of various methods.  Try `printf("%a %a\n", val, rounded_val);`.  Often, problems occurs due to imprecise understanding of the exact values used should code use `printf("%f\n", val);`

---

Further: "I already have upper and lower bounds of `val`, say `valU` and `valL` respectively. I can do this in the following ways:"

This is doubtfully accurate as the deviation of `valU` and `valL` is just an iteration of the original problem - to find `rounded_val`.  The code  to find `valL` and `valU` each needs an upper and lower bound, else what is to prevent range `[valL ... valU]` from itself having inaccurate endpoints?