# Floating point numbers in c

Tags: c

i need to convert the following statement to

```
x = 123456.789;
```

and print the floating point variable x with 3 digits before the decimal point and two digits after the decimal point.

**output**

456.78

What i have tried `printf("%6.2f",x);`

Comment: What if you use the modulo operator `%`?

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf how?

Comment: sorry for my mistake, it seems you have to use `fmod()` with floats in order to get the modulo operation result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

> floating point variable x with 3 digits before the decimal point and two digits after the decimal point.

What you need is floating-point modulo remainder function `fmod`

```
double x = 123456.789;
double y = fmod( x, 1000 );
printf("%06.2f",y);
```

Remember to `#include <math.h>`, and compile with `-lm` for the math library, example:

`gcc test.c -o test -lm`

Comment: Try `printf("%3.2f",1.234);`.  Suggest to "3 digits before the decimal point", use `printf("%06.2f",1.234);`  6 is the minimum width.  0 is the left padding

Comment: @chux yes `%06.2f` is better, tks