# Rounding function in C

Tags: c, rounding

So i am trying to write a code which can allow me to round UP any number to 3 decimal places. My code for rounding up a number was like this :

```
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++)
{
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++)
    {
         printf("%.3f ", ceil(rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] * 1000.0) / 1000.0);
    }
}
```

But yesterday my teacher told us to use a code which has a structure like this:

```
float roundValue(float value, int decimalPlaces)
{
      // Place rounding code here
      return value;
}
```

i am not quite sure how to write the code in this format! I am a beginner in coding so this might be so silly.

UPDATE:
so i just read all the comments below and tried to write the code but still has a problem. my code is :

```
double roundValue(double value, int decimalPlaces)
{
value = roundf( value * pow(10, decimalPlaces)) / pow(10, decimalPlaces);
return value;
}
int main(void) 
{
int rowIndex = 0;
int columnIndex = 0;
double rawData[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]; // 2-dimensional array to store our 
raw data
double value = rawData[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
int decimalPlaces = 3;
// Print out the roundup data array
printf(" --- ROUNDED DATA ---\n");
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++)
{
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++)
    {
        printf("%.3f ", roundValue(value, 3));
    }
    printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

it gives me only 0 for all the numbers.

Comment: You need to clarify your questions and describe steps you've already tried...

Comment: So, ask your teacher? And when you're at it, tell him using `float` is a **horrible** idea in general because of its limited precision ...

Comment: If you understood floating point binary representation you would not "*think*" of 3 decimal places. If you *REALLY* need 3 decimal places, try with a fixed point format.

Comment: return ( value * 1000.0 ) / 1000.0 ); // copies your rounding code (maybe a better way tho) as the return in roundValue()

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c#1344261), you could use the `roundf` function found in `math.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* function that rounds a float to the specified number of decimals */
float roundValue(float value, int decimalPlaces)
{
    value = roundf(value * pow(10, decimalPlaces)) / pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    return value;
}


/*to see the results: */
int main()
{
    float value = 12.34567;
    printf("%f", roundValue(value, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

> Compilation/run:

```
$ gcc -lm main.c
$ ./a.out
12.346000
```

Comment: Unclear why code uses `roundf(float)` and `pow(double)`.  It would make more sens to use `roundf()/powf()` or all `double` math and `round()/pow()`.

Answer (score 1):

He just told you to write your code in a function that you can call in the `main()` function.

So instead of rewriting your code every time you need a round value you can use a function, you give it the number that you want to calculate the round value for, and it will give you the result so your code won't be repetitive

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it can't be done. The problem is that 0.1, or 0.001, cannot be represented in floating point format exactly. So you can only round to the nearest representation rounded = floor(x * 1000 + 0.5)/1000.0. It's best to use the full accuracy of the double, then round at the last moment, for display.

```
printf("%.3g", x);
```

will achieve this for you. In combination with strtod it's also another technique for rounding.

Comment: Using `sprintf()` is a reasonable alternative, yet with `"%.3g"` variant output with large values, it makes sense to use `"%.3f"` with a large `char []`.

Comment: The `floor(x * 1000 + 0.5)/1000.0` approach gives incorrect results for many negative `x` and various positive `x` where `x + 0.5` is not exact.  `round(x * 1000.0)/1000.0;` would be a direct alternative.

Answer (score 0):

> .. to round UP any number to 3 decimal places.
>   my teacher told us to use a code ... like `float roundValue(float value, int decimalPlaces)`

Without going to higher precision, it is *very difficult* to meet OP's goal with the best answer for all `value`.

---

Rounding a floating pointer value a) up or b) to the nearest representable 0.001 (or 10<sup>-n</sup>) is usually done in steps.

1) Multiply by 10<sup>n</sup>
2) Round a) up or b) to nearest
3) Divide by 10<sup>n</sup>

```
float roundValue(float value, int decimalPlaces) {
  // form the power of 10
  assert(decimalPlaces >= 0 && decimalPlaces <= 9);
  int power_of_10 = 1;
  while (decimalPlaces-- > 0) power_of_10 *= 10;
  double fpower_of_10 = power_of_10; // or just use `pow(10, decimalPlaces);
```

Scaling by a power of 10 introduces imprecision.  This *slight* error is magnified in the rounding step.   A simple work-around it to use higher precision math.  Fortunately the coding goal started with a `float` value and `double` often has higher precision.

Scaling by a power-of 10 can cause overflow, yet that is not *likely* when `value` is `float` and the product is `double` which has a wider *range*.

```
  double y = value * fpower_of_10;

  // round
  double rounded_y = ceil(y);   // round up
  // or
  double rounded_y = round(y);  // round to nearest
```

The quotient will rarely provide an *exact* multiple of 0.001 (or whatever power-of-10) but a floating point value that is *near* a multiple of 0.001.

```
  y = rounded_y / fpower_of_10;

  return y;
}
```

---

Usage follows.  Recall that unless your floating point types use a `FLT_RADIX == 10` (very rare these days, usually 2), The result with only be *near* the desired "number to `n` decimal places.".  If done well, the result will be the nearest possible `float/double`.

```
 printf("%f\n", roundValue(123.456789, 3));
 printf("%.10f\n", roundValue(123.456789, 3)); // to see more
```

---

More: an easy way to avoid overflow issues if higher precision is not available or used is to recognize that great C floating-points values have no fractional part and need no rounding.

```
float roundValue(float value, int decimalPlaces) {
  float int_ptr;
  float frac_part = modff(value, &int_ptr);
  if (frac_part == 0) return value;

  double pow10 = pow(10, decimalPlaces);
  return round(value * pow10)/pow10;  // or ceil()
}
```

There are other small subtle issues not noted here. [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding), [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), [rounding mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking), `round()` vs. `rint()`, `nearbyint()`.