# Arithmetic mean program in C

Tags: c

I wanted to ask you because when I run my program, I get that the arithmetic mean of 5 and 18 is 11, not 11.5? I put my program in C:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void) {
     int a,b;
     a = 5;
     b = 18;
     printf("La media aritmética de %d i %d es %d\n", a, b, (a+b)/2);
     return 0;
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the types involved in the calculation and the format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code like below -

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main(void) {
     float a,b;
     a = 5;
     b = 18;
     printf("La media aritmética de %.f i %.f es %f\n", a, b,(a+b)/2);
     return 0;
 }
```

Currently, you are getting 11. Because when this operation `(a+b)/2` is happening, it is saving the result in an integer. Which is ignoring the floating point value.

**EDIT:** If you want to print only 2 floating points then do the following -

printf("La media aritmética de %.f i %.f es %%0.2f\n", a, b,(a+b)/2);

For more info please see this [Floating point rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

Comment: It gives the result with a lot of decimals. How can I put only the necessary decimals?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using int instead of float or double. Integer division in C will provide only integer result by rounding off the output. Please use float instead of int or typecast the solution with float.

```
 float c;
 c = (float)(a+b)/2
```

However these are very basic C questions. Please go through C tutorial or C books for these kind of answers.

Answer (score 1):

Change the data type of a and b to float/double.

Answer (score 0):

#include

int main(void)

{

```
 float a,b,c;

 a = 5.0;

 b = 18.0;

 c=(a+b)/2;

 printf("La media aritmética de %f i %f es %f\n", a, b,c  );

 return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code is **data type**.When dividing any numbers, sometimes it return whole or decimal value.

For eg,

Let divide **10/2=5 and 10/4=2.5**.
Thus,*be aware in allocate datatypes*.

For your problem,there are **lot of ways to solve**,

1.Change data type of particular answer storing variable

2.Change data type for all process involving variables

3.Change format specifier

4.Typecasting