# Using floorf to reduce the number of decimals

Tags: c, floating-point, floor

I would like to use the first five digits of a number for computation.
For example,
A floating point number: 4.23654897E-05

I wish to use 4.2365E-05.I tried the following

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float num = 4.23654897E-05;
int main(){
float rounded_down = floorf(num * 10000) / 10000;
printf("%f",rounded_down);
return 0;

}
```

The output is 0.000000.The desired output is 4.2365E-05.
In short,say 52 bits are allocated for storing the mantissa.Is there a way to reduce the number of bits being allocated?

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: [check this first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/2173917).

Comment: How does the title have anything to do with the question? There's no memory allocation being asked about? The title should be a short one-line summary of the actual thing you ask about. Otherwise it's pretty useless.

Comment: Take a look at [Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c) and the like. It's easy enough to Google for these things. In fact, I just noticed that it linked on the right hand side of this page and would have been suggested to you when you posted your question. get into the habit of checking those suggestions before posting.

Comment: I think you should try %E instead of %f.

Comment: OP probably wants to round the number to 5 valid digits.

Comment: note that `4.23654897E-05` is not a float and can't be represented closely in single-precision float (which has only ~7 digits of precision)

Comment: Print `4.23654897E-05*10000`, then explain why you think `floor` should round it the way you want.

Comment: Or just print `4.23654897E-05` in the first place...

Comment: Why do you want to use only five digits? Discarding imformation is usually not useful. Are you rying to fix rounding errors? The correct answer depends on what your ultimate purpose is. Better results are usually produced by keeping all available bits until the end.

Comment: Part of your question requests reducing decimal digits. Part asks about reducing bits. Which do you really want? Veltkamp-Dekker splitting reduces bits. That is different from rounding to decimal digits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm interested in using only five digits in my computation in order to check how the loss in digits manifests as error, while performing arithmetic operations.

Comment: @Natasha If `num = 5.123499E-05`, would you want  the result to be about `5.1234E-05f` or `5.1235E-05`?

Answer (score 2):

A number `x` that is positive and within the normal range can be rounded down approximately to five significant digits with:

```
double l = pow(10, floor(log10(x)) - 4);
double y = l * floor(x / l);
```

This is useful **only** for tinkering with floating-point arithmetic as a learning tool. The exact mathematical result is generally not exactly representable, because binary floating-point cannot represent most decimal values exactly. Additionally, rounding errors can occur in the `pow`, `/`, and `*` operations that may cause the result to differ slightly from the true mathematical result of rounding `x` to five significant digits. Also, poor implementations of `log10` or `pow` can cause the result to differ from the true mathematical result.

Answer (score 1):

The result is expected. The multiplication by 10000 yield `0.423..` the nearest integer to it is `0`. So the result is 0. Rounding can be done using format specifier `%f` to print the result upto certain decimal places after decimal point.

If you check the return value of `floorf` you will see it returns `If no errors occur, the largest integer value not greater than arg, that is ⌊arg⌋, is returned.` where `arg` is the passed argument.

Without using `floatf` you can use `%e` or (`%E`)format specifier to print it accordingly.

```
printf("%.4E",num);
```

which outputs:

```
4.2365E-05
```

After David's comment:

Your way of doing things is right but the number you multiplied is wrong. The thing is `4.2365E-05` is `0.00004235...`. Now if you multiply it with `10000` then it will `0.42365..`. Now you said I want the expression to represent in that form. `floorf` returns `float` in this case. Store it in a variable and you will be good to go. The rounded value will be in that variable. But you will see that the rounded down value will be `0`. That is what you got.

```
float rounded_down = floorf(num * 10000) / 10000;
```

This will hold the correct value rounded down to 4 digits after `.` (not in exponent notation with `E` or `e`). Don't confuse the value with the format specifier used to represent it.

What you need to do in order to get the result you want is move the decimal places to the right. To do that multiply with larger number. (`1e7` or `1e8` or as you want it to).

Comment: This answer explains why the result is correct given the output. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hmmm. OP says: "I would like to use the first five digits of a number for computation." It sounds to me like the goal is to round the value to five significant places for use in a computation, not to simply print five places. OP could be more clear on this point, though.

Comment: @DavidBowling.: Then how come OP is bothered about the representation or printing it? The question is inherently ambiguous. Now if I change the answer there will be a thought going on that I have been influenced by other answers. This is undesirable.

Comment: I agree that the question could be better worded, but I don't think that it is ambiguous. OP clearly states: "I would like to use the first five digits of a number for _computation_." Further: "I wish to _use_ 4.2365E-05." It doesn't seem that OP is worried about the printed representation except in that it is not as expected when the value of `rounded_down` is checked.

Comment: @DavidBowling.: Edited.

Comment: @DavidBowling.: Do you have any feedback regarding the DV? Or any feedback overall?

Comment: Feedback: from the edit history I see that at first the OP question was not answered, but instead you said that the result was to be expected, given the OP code. This is obvious, and not an answer. In its current form, the answer seems incorrect:  "...`= floorf(num * 10000) / 10000;`  This will hold the correct value rounded down to 4 digits after `.`." is wrong, or at the least unclear. Instead of multiplying by `10000`, OP needs to multiply by `10000 * 10e5` to get the desired 4 decimal places. Also note that the final value has been truncated, not rounded.

Comment: "I guess you get the idea what you need to do..." suggests that maybe _you_ understand how to fix OP code, but given the previous mis-statement, the overall answer seems unclear. Any of these may have been a reason for a downvote.

Comment: Minor: Note that `4.2365E-005` is not the expected output per C.  `4.2365E-05` is expected  (2 digits exponent).  Perhaps you are using non-compliant or early C compiler?

Comment: @DavidBowling.: That's way of saying ..I am not guessing answer I am saying that it should be clear to OP now. Secondly regarding the first point..`4.23E-05*10000..` I said that 4 dig after decimal point if it is written on expanded form not with exponent as you might have thought. Anyway I edited...

Comment: @DavidBowling.: Thanks.

Comment: @chux.: Thanks btw. My earlier comment said that I ran it in old compiler...now I ran it in latest gcc compiler - it gave the result as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go:

```
printf("%.6f", num);
```

Or you can try using `snprintf()` from `stdlib.h`:

```
float num = 4.23654897E-05;  char output[50];

snprintf(output, 50, "%f", num);

printf("%s", output);
```

Comment: Is this even producing the output as what OP has mentioned in the question?

Comment: well, if you combine first method to reduce numbers after coma & second one to read last four characters - it will work. Not the clearest way, but effective

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to use the first five digits of a number for computation.

In general, floating point numbers are encoded using binary and OP wants to use 5 significant *decimal* digits.  This is problematic as numbers like `4.23654897E-05` and `4.2365E-05` are not *exactly* representable as a `float/double`.  The best we can do is get close.

The `floor*()` approach has problems with 1) negative numbers (should have used `trunc()`) and 2) values near `x.99995` that during rounding may change the number of digits.  I strongly recommend against it here as such solutions employing it fail many corner cases.

The `*10000 * power10`, round, `/(10000 * power10)` approach suffers from 1) `power10` calculation (1e5 in this case) 2) rounding errors in the multiple, 3) overflow potential.  The needed `power10` may not be exact.  `*` errors show up with cases when the product is close to `xxxxx.5`.  Often this intermediate calculation is done using wider `double` math and so the corner cases are rare.  Bad rounding using `(some_int_type)` which has limited range and  is a truncation instead of the better `round()` or `rint()`.

An approach that gets close to OP's goal: print to 5 significant digits using `%e` and convert back.  Not highly efficient, yet handles all cases well.

```
int main(void) {
  float num = 4.23654897E-05f;

  //         sign   d   .   dddd   e   sign   expo + \0
  #define N (1    + 1 + 1 + 4    + 1 + 1    + 4    + 1)
  char buf[N*2];  // Use a generous buffer - I like 2x what I think is needed.

  // OP wants 5 significant digits so print 4 digits after the decimal point.
  sprintf(buf, "%.4e", num);

  float rounded = (float) atof(buf);
  printf("%.5e %s\n", rounded, buf);
}
```

Output

```
4.23650e-05 4.2365e-05
```

---

Why 5 in `%.5e`: Typical `float` will print up to 6 significant decimal digits as expected  (research `FLT_DIG`), so 5 digits after the decimal point are printed.  The *exact* value of `rounded` in this case was about `4.236500171...e-05` as 4.2365e-05 is not exactly representable as a `float`.

Comment: Could you please explain the following lines of the code                    
  '#define N (1    + 1 + 1 + 4    + 1 + 1    + 4    + 1)
  char buf[N*2]; '

Comment: The `1 + 1 + 1 + 4 + 1 + 1 + 4 + 1` relates to the comment above it - a buffer of up to 14 characters may be needed to print a floating point value with  5 significant digits.  Having said that, little reason to be overconfident about potential buffer needs - so I double it (2x).

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand this _a buffer of up to 14 characters may be needed to print a floating point value with 5 significant digits_.                          Also,please explain the difference between _float num = 4.23654897E-05f; and float num = 4.23654897E-05_

Comment: @Natasha Are you familiar with the difference between `float` and `double`?  Apply that difference here: `4.23654897E-05f` is a `float` constant. `4.23654897E-05` is a `double` constant.

Comment: Would it be wrong if we define as **float num = 4.23654897E-05** and **double num=4.23654897E-05**

Comment: @Natasha Nothing wrong with `double num=4.23654897E-05;` if changing the type of `num` is OK with you.

Comment: I'm confused.My understanding is, using float num = 4.23654897E-05 will allow a compiler to assign four bytes, double num = 4.23654897E-05 will assign 8 bytes.When you say _4.23654897E-05f is a float constant. 4.23654897E-05 is a double constant_ do you mean when we use float num = 4.23654897E-05 8 bytes are allocated and for float num = 4.23654897E-05f 4 bytes are allocated?

Comment: @Natasha With `float num = 4.23654897E-05;`, compilers convert text "4.23654897E-05" to an 8-byte `double`. As that `double` is being assigned to a 4-byte `float`, that `double` is converted to a `float` and assigned to `num`. With `float num = 4.23654897E-05f;`, compilers convert text "4.23654897E-05f" to an 4-byte `float` and assign that to  `num`. Both will certainly emit the same code. The 1st may also raise a warning like "warning: conversion to 'float' alters 'double' constant value" as `4.23654897E-05` and `4.23654897E-05f` have nearly the same, but different values. The 2nd will not.

Comment: @Natasha To simplify:  `0.1 != 0.1f` as 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a `double` nor `float`.  Given `float/double` have different preciseness, the approximated values used differ.

Comment: float numf = 4.23654897E-05f;
  float num = 4.23654897E-05;  printing these values upto 15 decimal places on a gcc compiler gives 4.236548920744099e-05
4.236548920744099e-05 as output.I didn't get any warning too

Comment: @Natasha A difference in output is not expected as both `float`s have the same value.  `4.23654897E-05f` and `4.23654897E-05` are different values.   Compilation did not get a warning because not all your warnings are enabled: -Wfloat-conversion in gcc.. ( or weak compiler).  Note that what you call "15 decimal places" is 16 significant decimal digits.