# how to call functions

Tags: c, decimal, rounding

I am trying to call a function that I created. That will take a double then round them to two decimal places.

I have tried to put the parameter "x" in the argument of "roundnum" but it would result in an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double roundnum(double x);

int
main(void)
{

    double n;
    int roundedn;
    printf("Enter the number:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &n);

    printf("Rounded %.2f\n", roundnum(n));


    return 0;
}

double
roundnum(double x)
{
    double n;
    int number = (int)(n + .5);
    return number;
}
```

If I scan in 3.145, the expected output should be 3.15000.

Comment: You are returning `int` from a function which is supposed to return `double`?

Comment: No; the output should be `3.00` because you forgot to multiply by `100.0` before rounding and then dividing by `100.0`.  And getting `3.15` might still be problematic.  Your solution isn't general enough for `double` values big enough  that they don't have an integer representation.  Negative numbers present another problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help if you don't give us the error message you're receiving. Without flags this code compiles just fine.

A couple of mistakes I noticed:

1. You are not using the argument passed to `roundnum()`. I bet you wanted to write:

```
double
roundnum(double x)
{
    return (x + .5);
}
```

2. As corrected in my code above as I simply got rid of it, `double n` isn't initialized.
3. `int roundedn` is unused therefore useless.

Comment: You haven't coerced `(x + 0.5)` to an `int` — which is the crucial step in the processing.  Otherwise, good.  (Formatting: you can indent the code by 8 spaces instead of 4 to have it indented at the same level as the bullet points.)

Comment: @fassn, (1) this question is not about 'error message' , it is about rounding of a double variable (2) returning (x+0.5) doesn't round to 2 decimal places (3) if x is a double, and the function is returning a double, then even adding a fraction doesn't actually mean rounding. for e.g. if x = 0.05123123123.., and we add 0.5 to it, it results in 0.55123123123 which would be returned. This is not the rounded-off resul. Please edit your code to reflect these problems, else it is not the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in your `roundnum()` function, you never assigned the incoming parameter value `n` to the variable `x` that is used in `roundnum()`. So x is never assigned and defaults to zero.

Logically, once the value of `x` is assigned to n the function works:

```
double
roundnum(double x)
{
    double n;
    n=x;
    int number = (int)(n + .5);
    return number;
}
```

And to simplify the function for better efficiency:

```
double
roundnum(double x)
{
    return((int)(x + .5));
}
```

Comment: This can never return any fractional number, so I don't know how could it "work" for you.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, there are multiple mistakes in this function:

```
double roundnum(double x);
```

- That function shall return a `double` and you return an `int`instead
- It is clear that you haven't understood how parameters are used. When you call `roundnum(n)`you are passing a local copy of n stated inside main's body to variable x which is the parameter of `roundnum()` . The `double n` of `main()` has nothing to do with the `double n` of `roundnum()`. Basically in `roundnum()`, you are using an uninitialized variable which is a logical error. The number you want to round is basically `x`.

This is the function with the above mistakes corrected:

```
double roundnum(double x)
{
    double number = (x + .5);
    return number;
}
```

Now let's talk about why this rounding function is wrong by terms of logic. You want a 2-decimal round but in reality you are just increasing any number with `0.5`. So what if I put as input the number `3.150` ? It's already rounded but the function would return `3.65` which is a mistake. I won't tell you how to fix this issue , consider it homework ;)