# Rounding a matrix to arbitrary precision using Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I would like to round a matrix `M` to arbitrary precision in Rcpp. It is particularly easy to do so in R:

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2)
M
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.04463484 0.1455878
[2,] 1.77416096 1.0787835

round(M,2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.04 0.15
[2,] 1.77 1.08
```

That turns out to be slightly challenging in Rcpp / C++.

There is a `round()` function, however, it unfortunately only rounds to the nearest integer. For output purposes, e.g. the `"%.2f"` format can be used to round to two decimals. If the rounded numbers are to be used in further computations, it is possible to round a single element to arbitrary precision by playing around with `floorf`, `roundf` and `ceilingf` functions using manually adjusted, different scaling factors, see the discussion and proposed solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c).

Hence, a possible way forward would be to apply above-mentioned approach to each element (or more efficiently, to each column) of the matrix `M`. This seems unnecessarily complicated and I was wondering whether one of you has a more efficient/elegant solution for rounding matrices to arbitrary precision in Rcpp.

Comment: You write "a possible way forward would be to apply above-mentioned approach to each element" and that is a general truth.  There is no other approach.  To a first approximation, _each and every_ Rcpp Sugar function eventually goes down to work on each element.  How else could it work?   Now, rounding is tricky.  There was just a discussion on the r-devel mailing list, and R Core member Martin Maechler just split off a test package for different / new approaches.  So you too should do what many of us do:  If you want/need different behavior, implement it. Rcpp is a toolkit.

Comment: I know there are reasons why this may be a bad idea with floating point math, but can't you just define `double round_to_n_places(double& d, int n) { return std::round(d * std::pow(10, n))/std::pow(10, n);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement it yourself using e.g.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector myround(const NumericVector& A, int digits = 0) {
  NumericVector B = clone(A);
  std::size_t K = A.size();
  for (std::size_t k = 0; k < K; k++) {
    B[k] = ::Rf_fround(A[k], digits);
  }
  return B;
}
```

In R:

```
> (x <- runif(10))
 [1] 0.5050331 0.8921151 0.4566404 0.5828360 0.6931808 0.9296267 0.3091896 0.4077148 0.9563310
[10] 0.6905403
> myround(x)
 [1] 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
> myround(x, 2)
 [1] 0.51 0.89 0.46 0.58 0.69 0.93 0.31 0.41 0.96 0.69
> (M <- matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2))
           [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -1.0852162 1.793925
[2,] -0.1912413 1.170089
> myround(M, 2)
      [,1] [,2]
[1,] -1.09 1.79
[2,] -0.19 1.17
```

Answer (score 4):

F. Privé has a technically correct answer.  But it, just like the OP before him, missed that the Rcpp Sugar function already does *exactly* the same:

```r
R> Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector mr(NumericVector x,int d) {return round(x,d);}")
R> set.seed(42)    
R> x <- runif(5)     
R> x    
[1] 0.914806 0.937075 0.286140 0.830448 0.641746     
R> mr(x, 2)    
[1] 0.91 0.94 0.29 0.83 0.64     
R> mr(x, 0)          
[1] 1 1 0 1 1          
R> mr(x, 7)        
[1] 0.914806 0.937075 0.286139 0.830448 0.641745   
R>
```

The confusion, if any, was thinking that the *default* value of the `digits` argument was the *only permissible value* for the number of digits. Naturally, it is not.

Comment: Ahah sorry about that. Because the OP said it was not implemented, I assumed it was not implemented..

Comment: I know how it goes. Even grep'ing in the headers can be imperfect (so I often grep in unit tests instead ;-) ).  As always, we could do with more/better documentation.  No worries, and no harm implied.  Was simply worth correcting.

Comment: I like this bookdown: https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/210_rcpp_functions.html. The linked section provides the R-like functions provided by Rcpp, and `round()` is one of them indeed.

Comment: Yes that is one of several decent contributed resources. But I can grep my sources or tests on my deployment machine so that is often quicker...