# Bug / error jquery calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

excuse me if this common question or newbie question..

i am wondering why JS calculation return wrong result, i have calculation like this

```
console.log(((11000 * 100) / (100 + 1) * 1) / 100);
```

when i using calculator it returns 110, but when i calculate using JS it returns 108.91089108910892

here's the example:

```js
console.log(((11000 * 100) / (100 + 1) * 1) / 100);
```

are there way to fixed this? or i am wrong doing the calculation?
i have try .toFixed() method but that's not what i want..

nb: i have read this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345768/javascript-calculation-error/14728473#14728473) but that is just rounding up the value not the result (mine is far different 110 to 108.91089...)

Comment: no hurt feeling, but i don't need the explanation, or the way it works, i just need to fixed this..

Answer (score 1):

The calculation is right

Here is how it actually looks

```
        (11000*100)
       ------------
         (100+1)*1
   _____________________
            100
```

The above translates to

```
       1100000           1
     ---------    X   ------
        101             100
```

Do this calculation following BODMAS rule and the result is 108.91(approx)

Answer (score 0):

When converting .1 or 1/10 to base 2 (binary)  get a repeating pattern after the decimal point, just like trying to represent 1/3 in base 10. The value is not exact, thus don't make use of common floating methods.