# How to round a float to particular number of digits after decimal point?

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a function to round a float in C or do I need to write my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497018/is-there-a-function-to-round-a-float-in-c-or-do-i-need-to-write-my-own)
>   [Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

I am looking for a function in c which could round my float variable to another float variable with two digits after the decimal point, help and demonstrate please.
thank you

**Update:**
I need this function for calculation purpose, not for printing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this just for printing out to the console? Or for some calculation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497018/is-there-a-function-to-round-a-float-in-c-or-do-i-need-to-write-my-own. Note particularly that floats do not exactly correspond to decimals; if you care that much about the representation internally, you probably want a proper fixed-precision decimal.

Comment: Or just store values in cents rather than dollars (pounds, euros etc).

Comment: You also want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/273383/8331

Comment: If, as @therefromhere suspects, you are storing money values as floats, stop doing that.  You are asking for sorrow.

Answer (score 4):

you may try something like this:

```
float a = 1.234568;
float b = ((int) a*100.f) / 100.f;
```

instead of `(int)` you may use `floor()/ceil()` according to your requirements.

Comment: I am new to programming, I am getting everything except:
what 100.f is supposed to do?

Comment: `100.f` is floating point number 100.0, if you write just 100.0 it will be considered a `double` and you might get type conversion warnings.