# SQL Query - Correctly formatting column values (created as REAL) as INTEGER

Tags: sql, db2

SQL Rookie here. Using DB2.

I have a table `People` with attributes `FirstName VARCHAR(20)`, `Salary REAL` and some others. I want to query with `SELECT FirstName, Salary FROM People` and receive this as the output:

```
FirstName    Salary
James        1000
```

but instead I get Salary in E Notation (because it was created as REAL):

```
FirstName    Salary
James        +1.00000E+003
```

How do I format the query to convert the values in Salary as numeric?

I tried using `SELECT INTEGER(Salary)` but it changes the Salary attribute header in the output to 2.

Comment: Does `select INTEGER(salary) as salary` work?

Comment: @Gordon, please put your answer in the answers section.

Comment: I hope this isn't a production database - [You shouldn't be using floating point to store money](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273371/real-vs-floating-point-vs-money) (also read the linked entry in the top answer).  Among other things, the (decimal) value `.1` **cannot** be accurately represented (how far away depends on a multitude of factors), so results can be surprising...  Yes, most cases of fractional math will have rounding, but accountants have _very_ specific rules for this...

Answer (score 2):

Your query:

```
SELECT FirstName, INTEGER(Salary)
FROM People;
```

Does not assign a name to the second column.  You assign a name using `as`:

```
SELECT FirstName, INTEGER(Salary) as Salary
FROM People;
```