# Development of Core Banking Application with PHP

Tags: cakephp

I am venturing into Full time software development for banking purposes. Now i want to know something, can i use PHP to design something like a core banking system with php / mysql (but at the same time would work on all databases).

in Business analysis, is it right? Designing Core Banking applications with PHP / Mysql? I see a lot of screenshots where they use html for that sort of thing.

What Core modules (functions) can one use (implement) in further development of that sort of thing?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, that you have to ask that kind of question disqualifies you in my opinion to develop a banking (!) application were security is an *extreme* critical factor. I've already seen a payment provider (Neteller) failing in providing basic security features for their API (you could access *any* account data and do transactions AFAIR) when I had to implement it for a site ~2-3 years ago.

php is suitable for the frontend but php has quirks with floats. Shops like Magento and others have already suffered from bugs and problems with floats. It must be also ensured that the DB and possible type conversions in the app don't cause wrong calculations. Rounding might fail as well. See [Real vs. Floating Point vs. Money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273371/real-vs-floating-point-vs-money) You will have to put a serious amount of effort into testing the integrity of transactions and calculations.

On the backend side that does the actually processing of the data there is very like no php running at all for any banking application. Depending on the age of their infrastructure I guess it is most likely Java or something really ancient. Security, security and again security, good performance, and redundancy are as well critical when designing such an application. This is far more than just "What language should I pick?".

> What Core modules (functions) can one use (implement) in further development of that sort of thing?

Seriously? This is so broad you could ask "What should I eat today?" as well. CakePHP is suitable for *any* kind of web application. No idea what exactly you mean. You should start with writing a *clear* and *detailed* specification and developing an architecture of the system even *before* worrying about the language or start writing code.

Good luck with the project and make sure you have a good lawyer and make sure your contracts keep as much responsibility for failure away from you. :)

Comment: I haven't tried CakePHP 3 yet but CakePHP 2 would stubbornly refuse to help you with absolutely basic database features like foreign keys, transactions or, well, clearly defined data types. But it had a CRUD generator that probably allows to create a banking site without programming knowledge :)

Comment: thanks burzum, Im most grateful for your reply. What i mean is that, im trying to make something like Flexcube or Finacle or temenos, since i have some good knowledge here i of php / mysql i decided to ask. on here.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Cake2 allowed you to do transactions.

Nnaerich Doughan "Core Banking" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_banking is a pretty broad term as well. As I wrote before, start with a *clear* specification and architecture before worrying about implementation details. Good luck.

Comment: AFAIK, Cake 2 replicates with pure PHP code all typical DB features, specifically transactions. Clearly, it isn't the same: if PHP crash, it won't rollback.

Comment: @burzum Corebanking i mean A possibility where someone can make transfers , Deposit and Withdraw and also Do application for Loan , Cheques and the rest. Also have Customer Related Management Systems.

Thats what i meant. I also see something like Finacle is Written in Java, and the class used as an Applet in simple HTML, could that be what u meant when you talked about frontend in php and backend java?